# 4020 error on refund in MySagePay

Tags: opayo

When trying to refund a transaction on MySagePay (test mode, haven't tried live) I keep receiving the following error:

> Failed refund attempt via My Sage Pay screens by *[redacted]*. Error returned was: 4020 : Information received from an Invalid IP address.

Since the information should be being received from Sage's IP addresses, I'm not sure why this is happening or how to fix it.

I've tried adding whitelisting the IP for `test.sagepay.com` and tried whitelisting my own computer's IP but neither worked.

Is this another case of Sage sending misleading error messages?

- If so, what steps can I take to find out the real cause?
- If not, what IP addresses do I need to whitelist to make their control panel work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the answer by looking at a different client's SagePay

For some reason, Sage didn't set its own IP addresses in the valid IPs when they set up the account

Adding the following solved the problem:

10.227.167.3

10.227.177.3

(Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.000)